# Index Values SumUp to Total

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to improve in my Problem Solving Skills and would love to get some explanation on what it is that I am doing wrong or if I can get a hand in the right direction. My code below is what I am stuck on.

My problem, I am trying to check within the array if it contains any numbers that will sum up to a total given value. Pretty simple but a bit complex for a beginner.

My first Step is to setup a function with two parameters that accept the array and total amount we want.

```
const array = [10, 15, 7, 3];

function sumUpTotal(array, total) {
    
}
```

Then I want to iterate through my array to check each value within the array by using the `forEach` method to output each value

```
const array = [10, 15, 7, 3];

function sumUpTotal(array, total) {
    array.forEach(value => value)
}
```

Now that I have all the outputs, I am stuck on how I can check if the numbers add up with each other to give out the total we want. Can someone please help.

The Output should be two numbers that add up to the total.

For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351826/algorithm-to-determine-which-numbers-in-a-list-are-the-sum-of-a-given-number covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over each value in the array and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if any values further ahead in the array sum to your total you can generate an array of unique sum pairs. By only looking forward from the given iteration one avoids generating duplicate pairings. (eg. avoids `[[10, 7], [7, 10]]` for you example input)

`forEach()` provides both the `value` and the `index` of the current iteration, which makes it simple to use the optional, second `fromIndex` argument of `includes()` to only look ahead in the array by passing `index+1`. If a match is found an array of `[value, difference]` is pushed to the result array. The return value is an array of sum pairs, or an empty array if there are no matches.

```js
const array = [10, -2, 15, 7, 3, 2, 19];

function sumUpTotal(array, total) {
  let result = []
  array.forEach((value, index) => {
    let diff = total - value;
    if (array.includes(diff, index + 1)) result.push([value, diff]);
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(sumUpTotal(array, 17)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as follows:

```js
function sumUpTotal(array, total) {
  // initialize set
  const set = new Set();
  // iterate over array
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    // get element at current index
    const num = array[i];
    // get the remaining number from total
    const remaining = total - num;
    // if the remaining is already stored in the set, return numbers
    if(set.has(remaining)) return [num, remaining];
    // else add number to set
    else set.add(num);
  }
  // return null if no two numbers in array that sum up to total
  return null;
}

const array = [10, 15, 7, 3];
const total = 17;

console.log( sumUpTotal(array, total) );
```